# Join two select queries in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to join two select queries but i am unable to get any results. Please help me to join these queries.

First Query ==>

```
SELECT *,all_posts.id as lid,all_posts.image as lpimage, users.image as uimage,all_posts.post_for_id as typ_id FROM all_posts LEFT JOIN users on all_posts.user_id = users.id WHERE all_posts.parent_id = 0 order by lid desc limit 5;
```

This query returns all posts irrespective of "access" field => Public, Friends, NULL

Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGTFI.jpg) for the result

Sample Data ===== all_posts table

```
id    user_id     image      post_type      post_date        access
==    ========   =====      =======    =========              =====
4526     1663   undefined    image     2020-03-07 06:47:04    Public
4523     196    undefined    image     2020-03-07 06:47:04    Friends
```

Users table=>

```
id    name    
==    ======== 
1663   test1  
196    test2   
1966   test3
```

Friends Table -

```
id    from_id      to_id    add_date    
==    ========      =====       =======
316    196          1966       2019-10-15
```

Second query ==>

```
SELECT count(*) as isfriend from friend where (from_id=:from_id and to_id=:user_id) or (from_id=:user_id and to_id=:from_id)
```

This query returns 1 or 0 based on of the current user is a friend of the other user(In my case i want to check with the each user_id from the above result of Query1).
Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRx8p.jpg) for the result
 My query ==>

```
 SELECT *,all_posts.id as lid,all_posts.image as lpimage, users.image as uimage,all_posts.post_for_id as typ_id FROM all_posts LEFT JOIN users on all_posts.user_id = users.id WHERE user.id = 1(SELECT count(*) as isfriend from friend where (from_id=:from_id and to_id=:user_id) or (from_id=:user_id and to_id=:from_id)) all_posts.parent_id = 0 order by lid desc limit 5;
```

I want a query where i can get all the Public posts from first query also the posts which has the "access" as "Friends" AND user_id is a friend of the current user.
 That means i have to join these two queries to get this. Please help me to get this right. Thankyou.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this could be the right direction:

```
SELECT *,all_posts.id as lid,all_posts.image as lpimage, users.image as uimage,all_posts.post_for_id as typ_id FROM all_posts LEFT JOIN users on all_posts.user_id = users.id WHERE all_posts.parent_id = 0 AND (all_posts.access = 'Public' OR (all_posts.access = 'Friends' AND 0 < (SELECT count(*) as isfriend from friend where (from_id=all_posts.user_id and to_id=users.id) or (from_id=users.id and to_id=all_posts.user_id))) ORDER BY lid DESC LIMIt 5;
```